# Matching forward slash in Oracle regexp_like

Tags: regex, oracle

The question that I am going to ask might have been asked before but I am not able to find any satisfactory answer for the problem I am facing.

I have written 2 regular expression to find out column in database starting with special character (non alphanumeric), below are the 2 regular expressions,

1. To find records with only special characters,

   ```
   select col_name from tbl_name where regexp_like (col_name, '^[^ 0-9 A-Z a-z]*$');
   ```
2. To find records for which only the first character is non-alphanumeric

   ```
   select col_name from tbl_name where regexp_like(col_name, '^[^ 0-9 A-Z a-z]{1}.*');
   ```

But the above queries are not returning me some documents for which the col_name value is forward slash (/) only. I am not able to understand that, why it is not returning any of these records. 
Also how do I confirm, the above queries are not missing any other non-alphanumeric character.

Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: please paste a value of a col_name not returning.

Comment: Hello Shawn, it is not returning the records, for which the col_name have value forward slash (/).

Comment: so you have some of `a_name` and some of `/a_name` ? I am trying to make an example for you, but you need to define your test cases well :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Some of the records have value which are starting with special character like (/abc, $abc, #abc) and others which have only special characters (/,#,$,%).

Comment: Actually, the [`^[^ 0-9 A-Z a-z]{1}.*`](https://regex101.com/r/rT6qB6/1) matches an entry with `/` only. Since you have literal spaces inside the character class, the leading spaces are not allowed.

Comment: It may be that your column doesn't start with a slash after all.  Perhaps it has a leading space character? The regular expressions you provided would exclude a column beginning with a space.

Comment: Thanks Sentinel for pointing it out. Yes, it was a space problem. Because of the space it was not able to find those records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
regexp_like(col_name,'^[^0-9A-Za-z]')
```

Which won't exclude col_names with leading spaces and only looks at the first character of the col_name.

Comment: You can cast as `regexp_like(col_name, '^[^\w]').

Comment: @ShawnMehan \w is not a good choice here since it include the underscore character which is not a legal first character for unquoted oracle identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

to find special characters

```
select col_name from test 
where not regexp_like(col_name, '.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 .{}\[\]].*')
```

Answer (score 0):

So it isn't clear what you are trying to match, but your regex seems odd to me. [here](https://regex101.com/r/tD9xU8/3) is a demo with test cases that you can modify. I think that your regex is

```
[\/#$%]?\w*
```

which has an optional `/` as well as `#` etc., at the start followed by any number of whitespace chars which are [a-zA-Z0-9]. You also don't need spaces in your class declaration.

So, along what @Moudiz wrote, construction is along the lines of

```
select col_name from test 
where rlike(col_name, '[\/#$%]?\w*')
```